# Linux Mint Taskbar and Icons are gone

Tags: linux-mint, desktop-environment, cinnamon, panel

I have linux mint cinnamon 13. I installed it today. Well my problem is that my panel and my icons are gone. There is absolutely nothing but my desktop background. But I'm still able to switch to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Also when I click on <kbd>print</kbd> on my keyboard it makes a photo but nothing pops up. So how can I get my taskbar, icons etc. back?

Comment: It would help if you specified your window manager/desktop environment.

Comment: What did you install today ? Linux Mint (complete) or just Cinnamon ? If you installed just Cinnamon, or you upgrade from a previous version using Gnome2, you must delete some hidden folder containing your previous configuration. Unfortunately, I can't remember which one exactly

Comment: I installed the complete linux mint.

Comment: And your home folder is also new ? or you had an other distro installed previously ? Have tried to create a new user ?